# Потоки в с++, лишний поток

Tags: c++, linux, pthread

Имеется простейшие код создания потока:

```
#include <thread>

void fun() {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
}

int main() {

std::thread t(fun);
std::cout << "thread created\n";
t.join();
return 0;
}
```

При этом при отладке в gdb я вижу, что при создании потока вместо одного, gdb сообщает о двух. Второй на протяжении всего времени не подает признаков жизни, и исчезает при выходе из программы вместе с основным потоком. При этом поток, в котором выполняется fun исчезает после вызова join (и завершения всех действий в функции fun). Если я создаю еще один или более потоков - лишних потоков больше не появляется. В чем дело? Откуда появился этот поток и зачем он нужен?

Comment: Не могу воспроизвести... можно полноценный [mcve], а также вывод `gdb` и заодно информацию о libc/компиляторе/ядре (и есть ли что-то ещё необычное)?.. отдельный управляющий поток был в древних версиях glibc, сейчас его быть не должно...

Comment: @Fat-Zer  полный код приведу сейчас в вопросе, но он не сильно то отличается. Вывод gdb тоже приложу. Что же касается информации о ядре - откуда ее взять, если не секрет?

Comment: про ядро, `uname -srm` будет достаточно, компилятор/libc — версии и, если отлично от gcc/glibc — указать

Comment: @Fat-Zer стоило только задать вопрос, как почти тут же нашел ответ: для отслеживания потоков я использую thread sanitizer и, по всей видимости, именно он и запускает дополнительный поток.

Comment: @Fat-Zer стоило только задать вопрос, как почти тут же нашел ответ: для отслеживания потоков я использую thread sanitizer и, по всей видимости, именно он и запускает дополнительный поток(потому как без него создается только один).

Comment: @Fat-Zer но, правда, основную проблему это не решает: я задал этот вопрос с надеждой понять, почему в моей программе (в которой слишком много кода, чтобы приводить сдесь) не может завешиться основной поток. Тобишь доходит до самого return в main, и основной поток замирает. Я думал, что он ожидает завершения этого "лишнего" потока, но, как оказалось, нет. Не подскажете в каком хоть направлении смотреть?

Comment: останови в gdb после возврата из `main()` и посмотри backtrace... я ставлю на деструктор какого-то глобального объекта... или какая-то функция зарегистрированная `atexit()`... и без санитайзера (и ещё какой-нить отладочной шалупони) собирать пробовал? может они глючат/конфликтуют...

Comment: @Fat-Zer да, действительно, проблема оказалась в синглтоне, в котором была рекурсивная блокировака мьютекса. И почему только я сам не догадался пройтись дебагером после return...?